# Error: User doesn't exist with this username: when using spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm building backend using Spring Boot + Spring Security and testing it with Postman.
For frontend I will use Android app.

Implemented `http basic auth`.

When I click on the Authentication tab in Postman and choose Basic Auth from the drop down box and then I enter username and password fields there it works just fine. But when I am sending raw JSON request body I am getting following error:

`org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: User doesn't exist with this username:`

I assume it is caused with this class

**CustomUserDetailsService.java**

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        CustomUserDetails userDetails = null;

        if(user != null){
            userDetails = new CustomUserDetails();
            userDetails.setUser(user);
        }else{
            throw new UserNotFoundException("User doesn't exist with this username: " + username);
        }
        return userDetails;

    }

}
```

But I am not sure why as it works with Postman auth drop down box.

Here is more code that I use:

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

   @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(encodePWD());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.csrf().disable();
        http
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/rest/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/secure/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll();

    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encodePWD() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

**CustomUserDetailsService.java**

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        CustomUserDetails userDetails = null;

        if(user != null){
            userDetails = new CustomUserDetails();
            userDetails.setUser(user);
        }else{
            throw new UserNotFoundException("User doesn't exist with this username: " + username);
        }
        return userDetails;

    }

}
```

**CustomUserDetails.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    private User user;
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return user.getRoles().stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getRole())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also I am using this to login user and to check if matches one in DB.

```
@PostMapping("/loginuser")
    ResponseEntity<Object> login(@RequestBody User user) {
        List<User> userList = userRepository.findByUsernameAndPassword(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
        if (userList.size() != 1) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException("Entity not found");
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(userList.get(0), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```

Is it even possible to use `https basic auth` for rest server api?

Or do I have to use some authentications with tokens like OAuth and similar?

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: `userRepository.findByUsernameAndPassword` will not work. Using a plain text password and username to find a user with an encoded pwd will of course not work. It also bypassed Spring Security. So don't do things like this. Also make sure that the user does actually exists.

Comment: You shouldn't be sending JSON as you are using basic authentication, Spring Security will handle the authentication part.

Comment: You are using Basic Authentication that doesn't have an endpoint. Just send authorization headers.

Comment: An example of what? Your postman is already sending the header.

Comment: Yes it is. But for example if I have a form to log in on my android up where do I send data on which endpoint if I don't use endpoint here?

Comment: If you have a form then why use basic authentication...

Comment: You didn’t answered my question. Can it be used for apps that have separate frontend from backend? Or is it not a good practice?

Comment: If you would understand you wouldn't be asking these questions. It is part of HTTP. Anything that uses HTTP can use Basic authentication as stated it doesn't mater if it is Spring Security in the backend or not. If you communicate through HTTP you can use basic authentication. If you should or shouldn't is a whole different question.

Comment: Thank you for answers but my question from beginning was should I? :) as someone who just started and needed advice of experienced ones. That the only thing I am asking should I and how to since I have tried and it’s not working.

Comment: No your question was is it possible, yes it is possible. The should I question is a different one and as stated isn't easily answered as it depends on a lot of things.

Comment: So it’s possible :) good! Should I use it... probably there is a better solution but from my knowledge I am yet not ready to build it. If you can and know can you then tell me why my code is not working as it is possible to use it. Or just point on something that can help to me and others who maybe encounter same issue.

Comment: Your code already works, you are posting a header it simply doesn't find the user. So either the header you are sending is invalid(would be a different error), or the user simply doesn't exists.

Comment: The user exists in database. When I am sending it over the auth login box it works fine. So I am guessing it’s something with my controller (“/login”) but don’t know. How can I check header?

Comment: Your controller doesn't play a role here, the error is from your custom service (unless you aren't showing all the code).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Postman Authorization tab, Postman constructs the corresponding Authorization header `Authorization: Basic <credentials>`, where `credentials` is the Base64 encoding of username and password.

You can see this header in your Postman request clicking headers and hidden.

This header is needed for Spring Security HTTP basic authentication. If you just post username and password in the body of the request as JSON, Spring Security HTTP basic authentication cannot extract the username from the header. Therefore, `user` equals `null` and the exception is thrown.

Comment: HI this is what I have in my `header -> Basic ZG9tZTpkb21lZG9tZTM1`. Please see my question update I posted pic as well. What do I need to do to make it work? To extract username from header?

Comment: @user9347049 You wrote *But I am not sure why as it works with Postman auth drop down box.* so it works. Nothing to do anymore.